# C1pdfviewer pagesize issue

Tags: vb.net, pdfviewer

Can anybody please help me regarding pagesize issue. I'm using C1PdfViewer in Vb.net. Below code I'm using it to open PDF but page size width I'm not able to increased. I tried `c1PdfViewer1.MinWidth` & `MaxWidth` but nothing hppns. I tried using `c1PdfViewer1.pageSize` but i dont know how to set property for width.

```
Dim c1PdfViewer1 As New C1.Silverlight.PdfViewer.C1PdfViewer
c1PdfViewer1.LoadDocument(oMS)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qzf7L.png)

Comment: I've had a quick look at the documentation [here](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1pdfviewersl/index.html#!XMLDocuments/RefSL/html/P_C1_Silverlight_PdfViewer_C1PdfViewer_PageSize.htm), and it seems to me that `c1PdfViewer1.PageSize= New Size(300,200) should work just fine. You may need to add this between the two lines in your code sample.

Comment: I tried like       c1PdfViewer1.PageSize = New Size(800, 1000) but it increasing the pdf layout size not the page size.